# Highlight entire row with some color Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery datatable. Using Json object i have feed the values in a table. In a table i have value as "FAX" in some cells. My question is i want to highlight entire row with some color which is having "FAX" value in a Table. I have tried below mentioned code but its not working for me

```
$("#pagination_table tr td:contains('FAX')").css('background','red');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also that code will only highlight the table cell, you would need

```
$("#pagination_table tr td:contains('FAX')").closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct name of the css property is **background-color**, also the entire row is the parent element.

```
$("#pagination_table tr td:contains('FAX')").parent().css('background-color','red');
```

Comment: That more like a comment and not a solution. `background` works fine too. That's not the issue.

Comment: -1 question was to highlight the whole tr, not one td and "background" works fine